# INPP Neuromotor Immaturity

Tags: abnormal-psychology, developmental-psychology

Can someone shed some light on this "[Neuromotor Immaturity (NMI)](http://www.inpp.org.uk/intervention-adults-children/more-information/about-ndd/)" syndrome that's been mainly promoted/researched by a UK group called INPP. As you can seen from that page, they take themselves very seriously, "diagnosing NMI", as if it is well accepted diagnostic term. There's a [Wiley book](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118736966,subjectCd-FA10.html) about it--written by the director of INPP--but not much else I can find... no Wikipedia page or much in the way of scientific articles about it. Is it some new term for an old thing, or what?

Comment: Found [this paper (Neuro-motor Maturity as an Indicator of
Developmental Readiness for Education)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2be5/a622c81176cab0b2d37fbc90254c15203a78.pdf) through Scholar, but this was presented at their own conference. And another book by themselves: [Assessing Neuromotor Readiness for Learning](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1119970687.html). Interesting to see whether they have anything peer-reviewed (at a different conference than their own) published.

Comment: @StevenJeuris: Thanks for that paper. From it I found that INPP exists since 1975. Unfortunately the name of the founder (Peter Blythe) didn't turn up much useful stuff insofar, because of more famous people with the same name... I take that back I found something relevant: http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/neuroskeptic/2014/03/16/inpp/

Comment: This is getting more interesting the more is dug up. Very nice question Fizz! I think with what you know now you could already write up a speculative answer which could potentially warn anyone googling for INPP later on.

Comment: Here's another paper that seems to mention it in the abstract: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9728285

Comment: Sidenote: I've searched the whole of Web of Science, and scopus, in titles, abstracts and keywords, and this, and the INPP papers, is all I could come up with. This is *not* a commonly used term...

Comment: I've found a "paper" with the same title as the proceeding paper Steven mentioned. Published in "TAC Journal". http://www.tacinterconnections.com/index.php/2-uncategorised/409-neuro-motor-maturity-an-indicator-of-developmental-readiness-for-education-1?highlight=WyJuZXVyby1tb3RvciIsIm1hdHVyaXR5IiwibmV1cm8tbW90b3IgbWF0dXJpdHkiXQ== I've found two papers citing the TAC Journal paper and the proceeding paper: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/1350293X.2014.890351 and  http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1471-3802.12046/full